# How do you change text inside spans in multiple places (without getElementbyId) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website where when you click on a button, the text inside the button changes to a random string from an array I made. That works fine, but when I try to make that button change the text inside multiple different spans, the function stops working altogether.

```js
let exampleList = ['Shelf', 'Book', 'Political Idealogy', 'Laptop', 'Smartphone', 'Printer', 'Bicycle', 'Backpack'];

function newExample() {
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (exampleList.length));
  document.getElementById('changeText').innerHTML = exampleList[randomNumber];
}
```

```html
<h2>Find Your New
  <button class="examples" onclick="newExample()"><span id="changeText">______</span></button>
</h2>

<p>
  What you need is a <span id="changeText">______</span> or <button class="examples" onclick="newExample()"><span id="changeText">______</span></button>!
```

Now I know you can't use an ID more than once, but there's no other way that works. I've tried getElementbyClassName, querySelectorAll and none of them worked.

Just to clarify, I want what appears in the button to appear in every span that I set the class = 'changeText'.

I hope someone can point me to where I went wrong.

Comment: getElementbyClassName or querySelectorAll are exactly what you need.  What went wrong?

Comment: `getElementbyClassName` should be `getElementsByClassName`, and I assure you that it and `querySelectorAll` work beautifully.

Comment: Add the js code you used for getElementsbyClassName and/or querySelectorAll

Comment: You probably tried to apply the `.innerHTML` to the collecion instead of each element.

Comment: keep in mind that `getElementsByClassName` and `querySelectorAll` will return a collection (an array) of elements

Comment: I simply changed the button HTML from an id of changeText to a class of changeText, and the Javascript from getElementbyID to getElementsbyClassName. That didn't work, and I tried a number of things with querySelectorAll that I don't remember now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give all the elements that need updating a common class name. Then, use `querySelectorAll()` to find them all. Put them into an array and then loop over the array items to populate them.

**A couple of other items:**

You don't actually need nested `span` elements within the buttons, just give the buttons the same class name as other elements that need their text updated.

Don't use inline HTML event handling attributes (`onclick`, etc.) as that technique is 25+ years old and **[has many reasons to avoid it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)**. Instead, follow modern standards and do all your event binding in JavaScript.

Also, only use `.innerHTML` when you are getting/setting strings that contain HTML content. When the strings don't have HTML in them, use `.textContent`.

```js
let exampleList = ['Shelf', 'Book', 'Political Idealogy', 'Laptop', 'Smartphone', 'Printer', 'Bicycle', 'Backpack'];

// Get references to the buttons
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

// Set up their event handlers
btn1.addEventListener("click", newExample);
btn2.addEventListener("click", newExample);

// Get all the elements that need updating into an array
var elementsToUpdate = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.changeText'));

function newExample() {
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (exampleList.length));
  // Loop over the spans
  elementsToUpdate .forEach(function(element){
   element.textContent = exampleList[randomNumber];
  });
}
```

```html
<h2>Find Your New
  <button id="btn1" class="changeText">______</button>
</h2>

<p>
  What you need is a <span class="changeText">______</span> or <button id="btn2"  class="changeText">______</button>!
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try an implement it on the real website.

Comment: Yeah, just gotta wait for the timer, really appreciate it.

Comment: Minor typo, var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2"); , should be "btn1", but fixed and working